# Unable to install the Sublime Text 3 package manager via Git

Tags: sublime-text-3

I have Sublime Text 3, and I followed the instructions to install the package manager:

> Git Install
>
> Since Sublime Text 3 no longer extracts the contents of
>   .sublime-package files by default, and the fact that Package Control
>   needs to read CA cert files from disk for SSL certificate
>   verification, the only viable install method right now is via Git.
>
> Please note, the Packages/ folder listed below refers to the folder
>   that opens when you use the Preferences > Browse Packages… menu.

```
cd Packages/
git clone https://github.com/wbond/sublime_package_control.git "Package Control"
cd "Package Control"
git checkout python3
```

However when I search for the package control command by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>, I don't see it.

How do I properly install the package manager?

Comment: did you follow [the instructions](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/package_control/installation#ST3) completely? Do you now have a `Packages/Package Control` directory? Did you restart ST3?

Comment: Use `View > Show Console` to reveal the Sublime Text console and note any messages you see appear here when you start Sublime.  They can be a bit cryptic but can often point to the issue.  Also note any messages that appear when you paste the Package Control installation code into the console.

Comment: The Instructions given at the webpage that MattDMo links to should be sufficient... just paste the python code into sublime (edit view) and make sure there's no leading spaces (indentation matters in python), and then paste into and execute in ST3's console.

Answer (score 0):

It seems one of the earliest releases of ST3 lists *Package Control* itself among the packages ignored by control bar.
Open `Packages => Settings` and remove *Package Control* from the list of `ignored_packages`.

[image]

Tracked [here](https://github.com/wbond/package_control/issues/874).